How to retrieve sleep and cycle tracking data from Google Fit to our app?
I want to get sleep and cycle tracking data from Google Fit to my app. I am aware that the API is no longer in use and we need to use the Health Connect app. I have retrieved most of the data, but I am having issues retrieving these two types of data from the Health Connect app.
HealthManager.kt
class HealthManager(context : Context) :  ViewModel(){

    val permissions = setOf(
        HealthPermission.getReadPermission(SleepSessionRecord::class),
        HealthPermission.getReadPermission(CyclingPedalingCadenceRecord::class),
    )

    suspend fun readSleepInputs(start: Instant, end: Instant): List<SleepSessionRecord> {
        return try {
            val request = ReadRecordsRequest(
                recordType = SleepSessionRecord::class,
                timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(start, end)
            )
            val response = healthConnectClient.readRecords(request)
            response.records
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("HealthConnect", "Error reading sleep records", e)
            emptyList()
        }
    }
    suspend fun readCyclePedalingCadence(start: Instant, end: Instant): List<CyclingPedalingCadenceRecord> {
        return try {
            val request = ReadRecordsRequest(
                recordType = CyclingPedalingCadenceRecord::class,
                timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(start, end)
            )
            val response = healthConnectClient.readRecords(request)
            response.records
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emptyList()
        }
    }
}

DetailScreen.kt
@Composable
fun DetailScreen(healthManager: HealthManager, navController: NavHostController) {

    val sleepRecords by produceState<List<SleepSessionRecord>>(initialValue = emptyList()) {
        value = healthManager.readSleepInputs(
            start = java.time.Instant.now().minus(30, ChronoUnit.DAYS),
            end = java.time.Instant.now()
        )
    }

    val cyclingCadence by produceState<List<CyclingPedalingCadenceRecord>>(initialValue = emptyList()) {
        value = healthManager.readCyclePedalingCadence(
            start = java.time.Instant.now().minus(30, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS),
            end = java.time.Instant.now()
        )
    }
    
    if (sleepRecords.isNotEmpty()) {
        Text(text = "Sleep Records:", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, fontSize = 18.sp)
        sleepRecords.forEach { record ->
            Text(text = "Sleep Records: ${record.stages}")
        }
    } else {
        Text(text = "No sleep records available.")
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))

    if (cyclingCadence.isNotEmpty()) {
        Text(
            text = "Cycling Cadence Records:",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 18.sp
        )
        cyclingCadence.forEach { record ->
            Text(text = "Cycling Cadence Records: ${record.samples.firstOrNull()?.revolutionsPerMinute} rpm")
        }
    } else {
        Text(text = "No cycling cadence records available.")
    }
    
}


but I am having issues retrieving these two types of data from the Health Connect app What are these issues that you are observing? Is the app crashing?

@BenjyTec I'm getting an empty list even though data is stored in the Health Connect app.

Do you see this log in the Logcat? Log.e("HealthConnect", "Error reading sleep records", e)

@BenjyTec I've added two log statements, one in a try block and another in a catch block, but only the 'Success reading []' log from the try block is being printed.

@BenjyTec any solution?

I only found that thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67197675/google-fit-api-sleepsession-returns-empty-sleep-sessions-array-kotlin As I am not familiar with Google Fit, I can't help any further here.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@BenjyTec "QR Code Scanning Issue" it would be great if you could help on this Qr code
